# Updating MongoDB document with a wildcard in field name

Tags: mongodb

Have a fairly deeply nested document, part of the nesting includes an object that's a hash of ObjectIDs and a corresponding object.  I need to update all the documents in the collection by updating just one value in the nested object.  So I'm aware that if I had a structure like:

```
{ 
  "name" : "Bob",
  "address" : {
     "street" : "123 Baker St"
  }
}
```

I could update all "street" values with the following shell command:

```
db.mycollection.update({}, {$set : {"address.street" : "124 Baker St"}}, {multi: true});
```

But in my case, the structure isn't so straightforward, it's got those UUIDs in there, and I want to update all. The structure is more like this:

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "addresses" : {
     "0934029572035702834234092834" : {
         "street" : "123 Baker St"
      },
     "0904958304959879873876862378" : {
         "street" : "123 Baker St"
      }
   }
}
```

OK< not a great example b/c in the real world you wouldn't want to change those addresses to be the same, but suppose for a moment that I do.  How do I get all of the documents to change all "street" values in the nested "addresses" object without having to do it OID by OID?

Comment: Is that really your document structure? I would highly suggest changing it when possible. I would expect something like: 
{
   "name : "Bob",
   "addresses" : [ {
      "type" : "your strange guid like thingy",
      "street" : "123 Baker St"},
   { type : "your 2nd guid thingy"
      "street" : "123 Baker St"}]}

This way you can update the array elements. You currunt structure forces an update command like "addresses.yourguidthingy.street" : "new street" instead of an array element update like "addresses.street" : "new street". Hope it's a bit clear...

Comment: As I said, it's a bit of a contrived example (I'm not actually dealing in addresses), but yes the nested document uses a GUID key and an object value for each element in the parent nested document.  Maybe a better example is that they represent data snapshots, but I've run into a situation where the snapshot history needs to have an property updated across all snapshots.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you know the UUID's :P It's not a array but nested document structure which comes to a update command like:

```
db.mycollection.update({}, {$set : {"addresses.0934029572035702834234092834.street" : "124 Baker St"}}, {multi: true});
```